# How to query a XmlDocument without using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml

I am using .NET Framework 2 and I am unable to use LINQ to XML. What would be the best way to execute the equivalent of a SQL SELECT that returns multiple columns from a XML file loaded into a XmlDocument object?

Comment: Or, consider using XPath: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Comment: XPath would be my second choice if Linq was unavailable.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Comment: Or, depending on the format of the XML, use XSD.EXE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.80).aspx) to generate a Schema, use XSD.EXE again to generate classes from the schema, and De-serialize the XML into a collection of those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use XPath and the SelectNodes function:

From the article linked:

```
System.Xml.XmlNodeList MSPressBookList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Publisher[. = 'MSPress']/parent::node()/Title");
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318499